# How to mock express requests/resonce when unit testing to placate the VSCode typescript compiler

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I'm building out a nodejs server using express and Typescript. Using jest I'm building unit tests for my controllers and middleware. I've noticed that the inbuilt TS compiler in VSCode isn't happy when I pass empty Request objects to my controllers when testing.

```
    it('should respond with json data when promise resolved', () => {
        const mockNext = td.function();
        const mockResponse = td.object(['status', 'json']);
        const captor = td.matchers.captor();
        const resolvedPromise = () => Promise.resolve({ data: 'test' });

        return BaseResponse.json(resolvedPromise)({}, mockResponse, mockNext).then(() => {
               td.verify(mockResponse.json(captor.capture()));
               expect(captor.values.length).toBe(1);
               expect(captor.values[0]).toEqual({ data: 'test' });
        });
  });
```

[image: Code snapshot]

What is the correct way to mock the request and response objects from Express to satisfy the Typescript compiler. My tests do run correctly, so I think this is just an IDE issue.

Comment: Instead of including a screenshot of your IDE, please include the text of the output that is a problem. Also, this is not an IDE issue, rather it is an error from the TypeScript compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is that the Typescript compiler (tsc) is expecting properly typed arguments to the `BaseResponse.json(resolvedPromise)`. However, since this is a test, the properly typed arguments are neither necessary nor available.

Instead, you need to tell tsc that some or all of these arguments are dynamically typed. You can do this through explicit casting of the arguments, like this:

```
BaseResponse.json(resolvedPromise)({} as any, mockResponse, mockNext)
```

[The `any` type means that the type of the value is not something that tsc should care about, and it will ignore all type checks involving `any`-typed values.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

Be careful using `any`, though since it makes the type system unsound (i.e., otherwise invalid programs will be missed by the compiler). If you use `any` too often, you defeat much of the purpose and benefits of Typescript.

In general, though, you can expect to use `any` often in your tests.